# switch to a different tab after form submission ionic 2x

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Navigating between tabs works perfectly when user clicks and with what i'm doing currently i'm trying to switch to a different tab after user submits a form

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs  [selectedIndex]="{{changTab}}">
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Home" [root]="setTab1" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab  tabTitle="Search" [root]="setTab2" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab  tabTitle="Lessons" [root]="setTab3" tabIcon="book"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab  tabTitle="Notifications" [root]="setTab4" tabIcon="star"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab  tabTitle="Account" [root]="setTab5" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs>
```

signup.ts

```
signUp(){
this.http.post('url',{'fullname':this.fullname,'password':this.password}).map(res=>res.json()).subsribe(data=>{
console.log(data(JSON.stringfy));
this.changTab=3
})
}
```

Comment: have you create @ViewChild for tabs

Comment: no please, can you show me how

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it will help you.

Create

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 export class ClassName {
   /*ADD this inside your class */
   @ViewChild("paymentTabs") paymentTabs: Tabs;
```

Add Here

```
 /* add paymentTabs  with # ion-tabs*/
<ion-tabs #paymentTabs [selectedIndex]="{{changTab}}">
```

Call Here

```
  /* Select tab via index*/
this.paymentTabs.select(1);
```

I hope it will help you.